# How can I create a bunch of types and make them available for import from other modules?

Tags: python, reflection

I am trying to create a series of types using [`type(name, bases, attributes)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) without explicitly assigning those types to variables, and then make them available for import from other classes.

What I have so far is something like this

```
src/
  __init__.py
  a/
    __init__.py
    a_module.py
  b/
    __init__.py
    b_module.py
```

In `src/a/__init__.py` I have

```
import inspect
import sys

for c in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules['src.a.a_module'], inspect.isclass):
    type(f'{c.__name__}New, (object,), {})
```

Then I would like to import the type defined above in `src/b/b_module.py` like

```
from src.a import AClassNew

a = AClassNew()
```

but this of course gives an `ImportError: cannot import name`AClassNew`.

I realize I can put

```
AClassNew = type('AClassNew', (object,), {})
```

in `src/a/__init__.py` and everything will work, but I'd like to do this for any classes defined in `src/a/a_module.py` without defining them explicitly.

Is there a way to get this (or something similar) to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by just updating `globals()` in `src/a/__init__.py`.

```
for c in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules['src.a.a_module'], inspect.isclass):
    new_class_name = f'{c.__name__}New'
    new_class = type(new_class_name, (object,), {})
    globals[new_class_name] = new_class
```

This adds the type with the correct name to the classes of this module and makes it available for import from other modules.