# How can I get mypy to either recognize or ignore dynamically imported types?

Tags: python, types, mypy, type-annotation

I have a Python project with the following structure

```
src/
  __init__.py
  m/
    __init__.py
    a.py
    b.py
```

The contents of `src/m/__init__.py` are

```
exec_str = 'A = type("A", (object,), {"x": 1})'
```

The contents of `src/m/a.py` are

```
from src.m import exec_str
exec(exec_str)
```

The contents of `src/m/b.py` are

```
from src.m.a import A
```

When I run `mypy` against this code I get

> error: Module 'src.m.a' has no attribute 'A'

I'm not sure if there's a way to get mypy to recognize this module. I understand that I'm dynamically creating and importing a type, so I don't necessarily expect mypy to work here, but I also don't know a way to get mypy to ignore it. I tried adding `# type: ignore`, but mypy says `misplaced type annotation`.

At this point, I can't get `mypy` to successfully pass at all. What can I do to get around this?

I should also say, I'd really rather not ignore all of `b.py` if possible. There's a decent amount of code in there (in reality) that would be good to type check.

Comment: I'm guessing that creating a stub file (`src/m/a.pyi`) is out of the question?

Comment: @mgilson Unfortunately, yeah. The set of types I'm creating are [dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690164/how-can-i-create-a-bunch-of-types-and-make-them-available-for-import-from-other#51690386), so enumerating them in a stub file would defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have too many great options here, unfortunately -- mypy can't really handle dynamically constructed types.

Your options include:

1. Modify `exec_str` so it reads just `exec_str = 'exec("A", (object,), {"x": 1})'` then do `A = exec(exec_str)` inside either module a or b.

   That way, you'll at least be assigning something to an actual variable in module b (though that "something" will be of just type Any).
2. Add the `# type: ignore` comment specifically to the import. So do `from src.m.a import A  # type: ignore`.
3. Restructure your code to lower the amount of dynamism necessary or use different meta-programming tools to accomplish the same task. Mypy has a basic understanding of metaclasses, for example. (I'm assuming you've already considered this option, but I figured I ought to mention it for the sake of completeness).

Comment: Hmm. I don't think 1 will work, because I'm constructing the types dynamically as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690164/how-can-i-create-a-bunch-of-types-and-make-them-available-for-import-from-other#51690386), so I won't know what `A` is. I managed to get 2 working (previously I was having issues getting both mypy and pylint to ignore it). I actually haven't tried using metaclasses (it's a bit beyond my Python expertise at the moment). If you have any thoughts how to solve my other question without using exec, I'd love to hear it. There's currently only one answer.

Comment: @KrisHarper -- to be honest, I'm not entirely sure what problem you're trying to solve, exactly. (E.g. I know you're trying to dynamically create types, but don't really understand *why*). I'm happy to try and give more targeted advice though, if you explain some of the background/context behind what you're doing.

Comment: Yeah definitely. The actual problem is that we have SQLAlchemy models for all our database tables. Each of those tables has a separate audit table in a separate schema. The audit tables have the exact same name, and same set of columns as the real tables, along with a handful of audit table-specific columns like updated time, etc. I had the idea of automatically creating all the models for the audit tables in their own module (`a.py` in this case) and use them in other modules (`b.py` in this case).

Comment: I was able to get this working with individual tables, but I would need to loop over all the models in my models module and create new types dynamically. When I did that, I wasn't able to get those types to import, hence the premise of my first question. I don't love the idea of using `exec`, but that's all I can get working at the moment.

Comment: @KrisHarper -- yeah, it does look like you're reaching the limits of what mypy can do. If you really want static types for your audit tables, probably your best bet is to just manually code each new model -- perhaps you can have each audit model subclass the corresponding non-subclass one, to help reduce duplication. This *is* admittedly tedious, depending on how many tables you have/how frequently you plan on adding new tables.

Comment: If you add tables infrequently, it might be worth the one-time cost to manually create your audit models/write a script that can generate source code you can just copy-paste. (Similarly, you could write a script that generates the source code of a pyi file you could copy.) If these models *do* change fairly rapidly, the dynamic approach might be the best you could do. (You could perhaps rig together some solution that will re-run your pyi-generation script, but that seems sort of fragile to me.)

Comment: Makes sense. Auto-generating stubs is a good idea. I think for now, we're fine with ignoring the type checking, since this will be used pretty rarely (in general, I feel that we shouldn't be querying our audit tables in too many places in production code). If it gets to be more pervasive, I'll consider a CI solution with some auto-generated stubs. Thanks for your help on getting the ignore working though.